# Keeping same dimensions when switching content

Tags: html, css, reactjs, layout

I have a toggle leading to displaying one or the other content like

```
<Checkbox checked={checked} .../>
<div id="main">
{
    checked 
    ? <Content1 ..../>
    : <Content2 ..../>
}
</div>
```

The problem is that the two contents can have different dimensions, which is ugly when switching. I don't want to force both components to some maximum height/width; instead I want to force the height of both to the height of the taller one and similarly for the width.

*Is this solvable with CSS?* I thought about displaying both of them over each other with the inactive one having zero opacity and no click events (and maybe also negative z-index), but I can't see how to force them both to start in the upper left corner while letting them to influence the dimensions of the `main` div (so `position: absolute` doesn't work).

In case, CSS can't do it, React surely can, but *is this a good idea or is there a better way?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:grid` to layer the two elements to be "swapped" in the same grid cell and adjust the `opacity` and `z-index` as required.

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label {
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .25em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input {
  margin-left: .25em;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .25em;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

#checker:checked+.container .content1 {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1
}

#checker+.container .content2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

#checker:checked+.container .content2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label for="checker">Tick This</label>
<input name="checker" id="checker" type="checkbox" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="content1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In sint amet vitae ea accusamus fuga blanditiis modi rem. Vitae iure, inventore corporis non blanditiis, ad optio ex molestiae repudiandae iste eos minus eligendi assumenda neque.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content2">
    <p>Just short text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like charm. I guess, grid is the only layout capable of this, right?

Comment: Pretty much. It's the only way of overlaying elements without using positioning